# How to migrate from my WAMP environment to using MSSQL?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, sql-server, wamp

I have on my local PC installed WAMP environment (using WampServer OS).
Now I would need to change one script from working with MySQL to MSSQL.
I have no idea at all how to proceed, where to download MSSQL, how to install it and how to connect with PHP?
Thank you very much

Comment: Have you actually *tried* googling or are you just asking here in case someone already has an answer prepared that they can simply post with minimum effort on their side? Most (if not all) of your questions have been answered before on the Internet. Really.

Comment: Tomalak: You are right on, I ask here first, if anyone has simple answer for me. But let me ask question.. don't you think you could ask the same question to 50%+ questions here? Do you think there's something that is not already answered and can be found by google search? With enough time, I can find nearly all my technical problems there.

Comment: That's the exact reason why I ask less questions than I answer here. Most problems have been solved already, and I consider it lazy bordering on rudeness not to try and solve a problem myself but leeching other people's time instead. Especially if the problem is trivial and the laws of probability dictate that a solution is easy to be found. Apart from that - in what way is the question programming related?

Comment: Thank you for education, I see all your points. I am trying to google it now.. already for 30 minutes and I am still not clear at all how to connect PHP with MSSQL in the best way. Yes, I will find the solution in the end.. but something straighforward would be very helpful. On the opposite of you, I don't mind asking questions, because I think people like to help and answer.. if they don't, they just simply not answer.. as happened here. How is it related to programming? I am sorry, I wasn't aware this is one of the 'answering' rules. Thank you

Comment: 'asnwering' rules = 'questioning' rules

Comment: Oh, I like to help and answer. The amount of answers I have given here should make that clear. I even answer beginner question that could indeed be solved through searching, imagine that. But I'd like to see a *minimum* effort in the question, and a clear problem encountered during that minimum effort. Just asking "I have this problem please solve it for me (because I am to lazy to try)" is not the right spirit. And yes, this web site is for programming questions. When you encounter a problem writing a query for SQL Server, you are very welcome here.

Answer (score 4):

- Download mssql express http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/express.aspx
- Familiarize yourself with one of the great database abstraction layers, for example PDO http://www.php.net/pdo
- Refactor your code to use the database abstraction layer
- You may need to rewrite the mysql specific things to "standard" SQL

Answer (score 3):

Start by getting Sql Server working.  If you are using an old copy of Sql Server (pre 2005) you will need to make sure ntwdblib.dll is present in your System32 directory, and removed from your PHP dll directory (ntwdblib.dll is installed with the enterprise tools, so you may have to install them on your PHP box as well).   Once you have Mssql querying properly, start finding where Mssql differs from MySql in your code.

A couple of tips:

1. The ntwdblib doesn't accept long strings (I think it is limited to 4k, but don't quote me on that).  You have to use Stored Procs if you are trying to process a string longer than 4k.
2. Try to use Sql Server 2005 if you can (see above), the ntwdblib.dll is ancient and has numerous issues.
3. [The PHP site is your friend for mssql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.setup.php).